# Refering to points data in SVG

Tags: svg

I have SVG that draws a polyline, something like:

```
<polyline points="500 10 500 20 500 30 500 40 500
    50 500 60 500 70 500 80 500 90 500
    101 500 111 500 121 500 131 500 141 500
    151 500 161 500 171 500 181 500 191 500
    202 500 212 500 222 500 232 500 242 500
    252 500 262 500 272 500 282 500 292 500
    303 500 313 500 323 500 33 ... "/>
```

I would like to avoid specifying the points in an attribute for the following reasons:

1. The number of points can get very large (1,000's of numbers) and having them inside an attribute makes the SVG hard to read and process.
2. This set of points is used several times in the same SVG and I would like to avoid repeating it for each line drawn.

I know that for text you can use `<tref>` to refer to text defined elsewhere. Can this be done for the points as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the [`<use/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/use) ([specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)) element:

```
<defs>
  <polyline points="..." id="foo" />
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#foo" x="100" y="100" stroke="#ff0000" />
```

However, there is no way in plain SVG to move the point data from the attribute. You'd have to use some other techniques, JavaScript, XSLT or other pre- or postprocessing to do this.

*Edit:* Don't try this at home, kids, but you could use XML entities to store the points in another place:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg [
 <!ENTITY points "[your points go here]">
]>
<svg>
  <polyline points="&points;" />
</svg>
```

However, I strongly discourage this solution, since it's foreseeable, that processing software will choke on this. I guess browsers to be fine with it (as long as it's no HTML5 context), but others like Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator, Batik and so on will perhaps not play this well.

Comment: I guess this is the best I can get from SVG. The points must stay in an attribute, but at least I can share this attribute between elements.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You _could_ use XML techniques (google for "XML entity definitions") to store the points elsewhere, but I guess, you'll run in problems with at least one processing viewer. And you cannot do that trick in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your case a <path> would be more readable and compact? The `h` and `v` commands (and their absolute counterparts `H` and `V`) come to mind seeing your example.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard about a way to do this in SVG.

I would think about writing a script that generates your SVG code instead of doing things like this manually. This way you can put more structure into your SVG. SVG is really meant to be generated, not hand-coded.

Seems you coould do with just two loops in your example.